# Get Spring Boot management port at runtime when management.port=0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spock, spring-boot-actuator

I'm looking for advice on how to get the port that was assigned to the embedded Tomcat that is serving the *actuator* endpoint when setting `management.port` property to `0` in integration tests.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.2 with the following `application.yml` configuration:

```
server.port: 8080
server.contextPath: /my-app-context-path

management.port: 8081
management.context-path: /manage

...
```

My integration tests are then annotated with `@WebIntegrationTest`, setting the ports shown above to `0`:

```java
@WebIntegrationTest({ "server.port=0", "management.port=0" })
```

And the following utility class should be used to get access to the application configuration when doing full integration tests:

```java
@Component
@Profile("testing")
class TestserverInfo {
    
    @Value( '${server.contextPath:}' )
    private String contextPath;

    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedWebApplicationContext server;
    
    @Autowired
    private ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties
    
    
    public String getBasePath() {
        final int serverPort = server.embeddedServletContainer.port
        
        return "http://localhost:${serverPort}${contextPath}"
    }
    
    public String getManagementPath() {
        // The following wont work here:
        // server.embeddedServletContainer.port -> regular server port
        // management.port -> is zero just as server.port as i want random ports

        final int managementPort = // how can i get this one ?
        final String managementPath = managementServerProperties.getContextPath()
        
        return "http://localhost:${managementPort}${managementPath}"
    }
}
```

I already know the standard port can be get by using the `local.server.port` and there seems to be some equivalent for the management endpoint named `local.management.port`. But that one seems to have a different meaning. The [official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-discover-the-http-port-at-runtime) doesn't mention a way to do this.

Is there currently any undocumented way to get a hand on that management port?

---

## Solution Edit

As I am using the [Spock Framework](https://spockframework.org/) and [spock-spring](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring) module for testing my Spring Boot application, I have to initialize the application like this:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = MyApplication.class)
```

Somehow spock-spring or the test-initialization seems to affect the evaluation of the `@Value` Annotation so that `@Value("${local.management.port}")` resulted in

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
> 'local.management.port' in string value "${local.management.port}"

With your solution I knew the property existed, so I simply use the Spring `Environment` directly to retrieve the property-value at test runtime:

```java
@Autowired
ManagementServerProperties managementServerProperties

@Autowired
Environment environment

public String getManagementPath() {
    final int managementPort = environment.getProperty('local.management.port', Integer.class)
    final String managementPath = managementServerProperties.getContextPath()
    
    return "http://localhost:${managementPort}${managementPath}"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I've done it, copied straight from my test class (I use [RestAssured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured) for assertions):

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.WebIntegrationTest;

import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.get;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true, value = {"management.port=0", "management.context-path=/admin"})
@DirtiesContext
public class ActuatorEndpointTest {

    @Value("${local.management.port}")
    private int localManagementPort;

    @Test
    public void actuatorHealthEndpointIsAvailable() throws Exception {

        String healthUrl = "http://localhost:" + localManagementPort + "/admin/health";
        get(healthUrl)
                .then()
                .assertThat().body("status", equalTo("UP"));
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you @dave-bower, seeing your solution hinted me in the right direction.

Comment: My problem was, that I am using the Spock-Framework and Spock-Spring, where this property does not resolve when using the `@Value` Annotation. 

Propably because I'm initializing my Tests using `@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = MyApplication.class)`.

I will edit my question and add the solution for my Spock-Testing Environment there.

Answer (score 13):

Management port needs to be set to 0 via the `@SpringBootTest`'s properties field and then to get the port in the tests use `@LocalServerPort` and/or `@LocalManagementPort` annotations.

Examples:

From Spring Boot 2.0.0:
`properties = {"management.server.port=0"}`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
        "management.server.port=0" })
public class HealthCheckIT {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @LocalManagementPort
    int managementPort;

    @Test
    public void testManagementPort() {
        webTestClient
                .get().uri("http://localhost:" + managementPort + "/actuator/health")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

For older versions: [1.4.0 - 1.5.x]:
`properties = {"management.port=0"}`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = {
    "management.port=0", "management.context-path=/admin" })
public class SampleTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int port;

    @LocalManagementPort
    int managementPort;
```

Comment: this needs import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;

Comment: On Spring Boot 2.0.0 the property `management.port` was changed to `management.server.port`

Answer (score 0):

This is an update on @magiccrafter answer which requires the following to work properly

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it requires this annotation as well

@AutoConfigureWebTestClient