# @Value("${local.server.port}") not working in Spring boot 1.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am upgrading Spring Boot from 1.3 to 1.5. For upgrading to 1.5 I have replaced

`@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
 @WebIntegrationTest`

with

`@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)`

Also, I am using

`@Value("${local.server.port}")
 protected int port;`

to get port number defined in `application.properties` file. I further use this port number to build a REST URL.

But after the upgrade I am getting the error below whereas the same works fine with `1.3` Spring Boot Test.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"
>       at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)

Am I missing any changes that I need to do for this to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567207/get-spring-boot-management-port-at-runtime-when-management-port-0

Comment: I have tried using the `Environment` to get the port but it is returning -1

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary can u please post application.properties i.e. where u specified this property ?

Comment: As mentioned in the migration guide from 1.3 to 1.4 (which you skipped) use `@LocalServerPort` on your field instead of `@Value`.

Answer (score 12):

You have to provide a value for `webEnvironment`. In your case **DEFINED_PORT** like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class YourTest {

  @LocalServerPort           // shorthand for @Value("${local.server.port}")
  private Integer port;
  ...
}
```

For details see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications

Answer (score 4):

Adding another alternate solution which I had elsewhere.

I had configured

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class YourTest {

  @LocalServerPort           // shorthand for @Value("${local.server.port}")
  private Integer port;
  ...
}
```

Thinking that was it, and still getting this error even when specifying web environment etc. My `${local.server.port}` seemed to be always null.

After some time, I noticed that my Spring Boot startup message contained no notion of the port it was using, so apparently it really didn't listen to any port at all - which explained why it was null in the first place. Adding actual container implementation dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Caused this to appear on my logs:

```
2019-02-26 18:45:47.231  INFO 12504 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer  : Jetty started on port(s) 43132 (http/1.1) with context path '/'
```

after which local.server.port and @LocalServerPort would also work.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that there was alternative `@Configuration` class(es) in my other test(s) like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ReadPropertiesConfiguration {
    @Bean
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propConfig() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        placeholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("application.properties"));
        return placeholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

and `@SpringBootApplication` of the app was picking that up due to its @ComponentScan, and for some reason it resulted in this problem. When adding exclusion for those and/or replacing them with other solutions things started again to work without problems.

I don't know the root cause why this happens, but that might be your issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the property is correctly spelled in the properties file. As i did just few days back using spring-boot-1.5.2 & it works.

Or

You need to add

> @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

to your class, so it will pick your configurations.

If you need different configurations for test you can add

> @TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")

Refer [@Value not work on Spring Boot Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256702/value-not-work-on-spring-boot-test)

Comment: There is no problem with the code itself because it is working fine with spring boot 1.3.8.

Comment: Ok yes might be. Can u post some code classes also ?
It may help to see what is the issue.

Comment: Are you using maven based project ?